# javascript, sum array's positions in a loop, how to do it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

If I have an array and I want to iterate trouht it, but I need to divide contents(create another arrays when position1 is equal...) how to do it?

```
array={123,1,2,3,4}
array={123,12,21,23}
array={122,43,23,12}
array={122,234,122,34}
```

It's the same array always, it comes from a loop, I need to sum them, but in groups, these groups are divided by the first position, so how to do it?

My code structure example (non obviously working ):

```
    for(i=0; i< s.length; i++){

        for(i=0; i< 3; i++){
        c1=c1+parseInt(array[2]);
}
}
```

PD; yup I need two loops.

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand what you're asking for. What is the expected output?

Comment: array={123,1,2,3,4}
array={123,12,21,23}
array={122,43,23,12}
array={122,234,122,34}

These aren't actually arrays. Arrays in JS use []

Comment: What do you mean by this? _I need to sum them, but in groups, these groups are divided by the first position_